# Tools for presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

I'd like to know a good tool for job presentation (an internship), actually PowerPoint is not good, so I want to change....I know prezi, is it good? Any other suggestions, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get good results, you have to learn some basics about graphic design and communication and don't rely so much on the presentation program. Here are some links on how to improve presentations:

- http://de.slideshare.net/thecroaker/death-by-powerpoint
- http://www.darrenbarefoot.com/archives/2007/09/everything-i-know-about-presentations-i-learned-in-theatre-school.html
- http://www.presentationzen.com/

If you know some HTML, you can try using one of the HTML presentation libraries out there:

- http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy/
- http://goessner.net/articles/slideous/slideous.html
- http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/
- http://seld.be/notes/introducing-slippy-html-presentations

If it's not too nerdy for you, you can also have a look at [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/), an OpenGL PDF viewer.